# Solution for partial differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How to solve this partial differential equation
$$a(1-q)\frac{\partial}{\partial q}A[p,q]+(bp(q-1)+c(1-p))\frac{\partial}{\partial p}A[p,q]-(s+d(1-p))A[p,q]=0$$

where $a,b,c,d$ and $s$ are constants and $A$ is a function of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @Boris  I don't have any idea about how to solve this one. I got stucked with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dq}{dt}=a(1-q)$ , letting $q(0)=2$ , we have $q=e^{-at}+1$

$\dfrac{dp}{dt}=bp(q-1)+c(1-p)=(be^{-at}-c)p+c$

$\dfrac{dp}{dt}-(be^{-at}-c)p=c$

I.F. $=e^{-\int(be^{-at}-c)~dt}=e^{\frac{be^{-at}}{a}+ct}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\frac{be^{-at}}{a}+ct}p\right)=ce^{\frac{be^{-at}}{a}+ct}$

$e^{\frac{be^{-at}}{a}+ct}p=c\int_k^te^{\frac{be^{-a\tau}}{a}+c\tau}~d\tau+p_0$

$p=ce^{-\frac{be^{-at}}{a}-ct}\int_k^te^{\frac{be^{-a\tau}}{a}+c\tau}~d\tau+p_0e^{-\frac{be^{-at}}{a}-ct}$

$p=c(q-1)^\frac{c}{a}e^{-\frac{b(q-1)}{a}}\int_k^{-\frac{\ln(q-1)}{a}}e^{\frac{be^{-a\tau}}{a}+c\tau}~d\tau+p_0(q-1)^\frac{c}{a}e^{-\frac{b(q-1)}{a}}$

$\dfrac{dA}{dt}=s+d(1-p)=s+d-cde^{-\frac{be^{-at}}{a}-ct}\int_k^te^{\frac{be^{-a\tau}}{a}+c\tau}~d\tau+p_0de^{-\frac{be^{-at}}{a}-ct}$

$A[p,q]=(s+d)t-cd\int_m^te^{-\frac{be^{-ar}}{a}-cr}\int_k^re^{\frac{be^{-a\tau}}{a}+c\tau}~d\tau~dr+p_0d\int_m^te^{-\frac{be^{-ar}}{a}-cr}~dr+f(p_0)$

$A[p,q]=-\dfrac{(s+d)\ln(q-1)}{a}-cd\int_m^{-\frac{\ln(q-1)}{a}}\int_k^re^{\frac{b(e^{-a\tau}-e^{-ar})}{a}+c(\tau-r)}~d\tau~dr+pd(q-1)^{-\frac{c}{a}}e^\frac{b(q-1)}{a}\int_m^{-\frac{\ln(q-1)}{a}}e^{-\frac{be^{-ar}}{a}-cr}~dr-cd\int_k^{-\frac{\ln(q-1)}{a}}\int_m^{-\frac{\ln(q-1)}{a}}e^{\frac{b(e^{-a\tau}-e^{-ar})}{a}+c(\tau-r)}~d\tau~dr+f\left(p(q-1)^{-\frac{c}{a}}e^\frac{b(q-1)}{a}-c\int_k^{-\frac{\ln(q-1)}{a}}e^{\frac{be^{-a\tau}}{a}+c\tau}~d\tau\right)$